# Ng-repeat does'nt works with array in array

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm new at ionic and i need to loop trough object with ng-repeat and i always get this error

Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: info in allInfos, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value:

"[this is my arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuVXa.png)

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="items in objectArr">
     <div class="list">
          <a class="item" href="#">{{items['name']}}</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate error occurs due to the duplicate in the value for the `tack by` expression. Its better to track by the `$index` in `ng-repeat`. Try this one.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Array track by $index">
    {{item}}
</div>
```